# (Leak Detection) IoT Data Push via JSON to Database (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, json, iot

Does anyone know a simple way to set up JSON to my Raspberry Pi to MYSQL database from an IoT Wi-Fi Leak Detector (i.e. [Samsung's](https://www.amazon.ca/Samsung-SmartThings-Sensor-Automate-GP-U999SJVLCDA/dp/B07F951JDP/ref=sr_1_5?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0pa2kMKQ5gIVApSzCh0ncAVTEAAYAiAAEgIAFvD_BwE&hvadid=249275034140&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9061009&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t2&hvqmt=b&hvrand=15152256801963319744&hvtargid=kwd-299727978842&hydadcr=23086_10300080&keywords=smartthings%20water%20leak%20sensor&qid=1575068163&sr=8-5) or [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000204457068.html) Leak Detector) on an interval of every 60 minutes with three states?

1. Wet
2. Not Wet
3. Lost Connection

Please note: I'm aware there are pre-made paid apps but I'd like to try making something myself to avoid any additional reoccurring costs. I'm new to this project but very excited to try using IoT devices for my home.

Thanks for anyone's help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: note that you are looking for something that will send data to your MYSQL database. Phpmyadmin is just a web interface to display and interact with mysql databases

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @oo33 kindly look at he answer and mark it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is it possible for you to be more specific with your answer? I.e. which leak detector you'd recommend, how/what the java JSON command would look like etc. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One of those links says "Push notification to user smartphone" -- Need more information on the details of such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi support Python, C, C++, Java, Scratch, and Ruby by default.

**pushing via Json depends on the DBDriver**. node(js),python will push data via json. Java jdbc has its own protocols.

**you can write code to push data into mysql.**

In java you can use jdbc connection.
and each of the language has connection tools which can connect to db.

`for Java - https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

In java, In you are looking for ready-made components you can use open-source like spring boot data or any other tools

for python - https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/mysql-python
for ruby - http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/ `

create db schema (i.e db tables)
you use insert statement to push data into mysql table.